# On statefull processing how should you deal with data that was not processed due to never reach buffer size?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, stateful

I'm doing some aggregations on keys, on a global window. I'm buffering events to batch process only when reaches the buffer size, in order to reduce the number of iterations.

But, some keys never reach the buffer size, and aren't calculated.

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
DoFN<> {
  @StateId("count")
  private final StateSpec<ValueState<Integer>> countState = StateSpecs.value();
  private static final int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;
     @ProcessElement () {
       int count = firstNonNull(countState.read(), 0);
       count = count + 1;
       countState.write(count);
       if (count >= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
           (...)
           countState.clear();
       }
     }
  }
```

That works good, but i'm losing some data, since some keys never reach 1000 records to trigger the batch processing.

Answer (score 1):

I think proper solution here will be a to add a [FinishBundle](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.java#L658) method and finalize keys that did not reach buffer size at the finalizeBundle() method.